# develop crossplatform GUI based DESKTOP application with HTML5/CSS

Tags: html, linux, gui, cross-platform, desktop-application

I'm experienced wed developer doing stuff for web for a several years. But now my customer need to build crossplatform ETL tool which he want to ship to his clients. And will be much easier if it will be desktop application.

However I don't have good expertize in this field and in general don't feel great about desktop approach used in WinForms(or similar technologies) with button handlers, etc.

So in mobile application it's whole bunch of tools which allow developers write mobile app with HTML5/CSS like Apache Cordova for example.

Is there is something similar for desktop applications? If yes, does gui based on that still have similar response time as normal desktop apps?

Comment: Just use winforms already. Everything html/css is just one hackjob piled upon another.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there are a lot of cross-platform applications written using HTML5. You'll often see them using containers like [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/), [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron), or others. They run node.js generally and you can use npm just like you might be familiar with on the server. This also allows you to access the filesystem, networking, and many other OS features in a cross-platform way.

Depends a lot on your requirements though. Just like with the web you'd need a UI framework that fits your client's goals.

> Does gui based on that still have similar response time as normal desktop apps

From my experience, since they all use Blink, the performance is comparable to Windows Forms/WPF.

Comment: Thanks. This looks closer to what I'm looking for. However in my case application is pretty complex and write it clearly on javascript will not be a good idea.